# my JavaScript todolist not deleting the last item remaining

Tags: javascript, splice

when I add multiple items to this list, and then try to delete all, the last item remaining always stays on the page, any help?

I tried Splice() to delete each item when I click delete, and even consoled.log the todo array, and all items are deleted successfully using the delete button, but it doesn't actually delete it on the page.

```js
const todoList = [];
const newItemAdd = document.getElementById("newItemAdd");
const reset = document.getElementById("reset");

newItemAdd.onclick = addItem;
newItemTitle.onkeydown = function press() {
  if (event.key === "Enter") {
    addItem();
  }
};

function addItem() {
  let todoListRender = "";
  if (newItemTitle.value !== "") {
    todoList.push(newItemTitle.value);
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < todoList.length; i++) {
    const todo = todoList[i];
    let html = `
      <p>
        ${todo}
        <button onclick="
          todoList.splice(${i}, 1);
          addItem();
          console.log(todoList);
        ";>Delete</button>
      </p>
      `;
    todoListRender += html;
    document.querySelector("#todoDiv").innerHTML = todoListRender;
    newItemTitle.value = "";
  }
}

reset.onclick = function () {
  todoList.length = 0;
  newItemTitle.value = "";
  document.querySelector("#todoDiv").innerText = "";
  addItem();
};
```

```html
<p id='title'>Todo List</p>
<input id='newItemTitle' placeholder='Todo name'>
<input type='date' id='newItemDate'>
<button id='newItemAdd'>Add</button>
<button id='reset' class='test'>Reset</button>
<div id='todoDiv'></div>
```

Comment: alright, I'm new here, thank you.

Comment: I removed the link, pasted the code.

Comment: @James, I inspected the html, and when there is only 1 item remaining, it has splice(0, 1) and when I 'delete' to run the splice, the item is deleted from the array according to the console and returns a blank array. so could it be another error?

Comment: You're right Ahmed, the splice thing was not relevant.  Note that you do `document.querySelector("#todoDiv").innerHTML = todoListRender;` inside the for loop, and the for loop only happens if there are elements in the array.

Comment: You're right, James! getting the render out of the for loop fixed it finally :).

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes to the code that fixes your problem. You can see that here:
https://codepen.io/noex98/pen/zYmKgpG?editors=1011

Honestly, i am unaware what exactly caused your problem. But i think there was a better way of approaching the problem.

Instead of having a function that adds items to the DOM. I made a function that would sync the data you have in your array with the DOM. I named this function `renderTodoList`

That makes it quite easy to add and delete todo items. Whenever you change the data, you just make sure to call `renderTodoList`, and that will synchronize the DOM with the items in your array.

Hope this is helpfull, even though i couldn't find the exact problem :)

```js
const todoList = [];
const newItemAdd = document.getElementById("newItemAdd");
const reset = document.getElementById("reset");

newItemAdd.onclick = addTodo;
newItemTitle.onkeydown = () => {
  if (event.key === "Enter") {
    addTodo();
  }
};

function addTodo(){
  if(!!newItemTitle){
    todoList.push(newItemTitle.value);
    newItemTitle.value = "";
    renderTodoList();
  }
}

function renderTodoList() {
  let todoListHTML = "";
  todoList.forEach((todo, i) => {
    todoListHTML += `
      <p>
        ${todo}
        <button onclick="
          todoList.splice(${i}, 1);
          renderTodoList();
        ";>Delete</button>
      </p>
    `;
  })
  document.querySelector("#todoDiv").innerHTML = todoListHTML;
}

reset.onclick = () => {
  todoList.length = 0;
  renderTodoList();
};
```

```html
<p id='title'>Todo List</p>
<input id='newItemTitle' placeholder='Todo name'>
<input type='date' id='newItemDate'>
<button id='newItemAdd'>Add</button>
<button id='reset' class='test'>Reset</button>
<div id='todoDiv'></div>
```

Comment: @Noex98, this looks like a more advanced approach, thank you so much I'll learn from your code for sure. it works fine

Comment: No problem, @AhmedAnwer. The approach is actually very similar to what you are already doing. The difference is that it splits the dom manipulation into its own function ;)
Is my answer a good solution for you, or would you like to dive deeper into what exactly is the issue in the code you provided?

Comment: @James just got the solution for this, the problem with my code is that I updated the list inside the for loop "document.querySelector("#todoDiv").innerHTML = todoListRender;" so I just mved it outside the for loop, but still inside the function for sure, and it worked fine finally :)               but what I learned from your code I guess, is that I should separate two different concepts like rendering the list on the page and actually adding/removing to/from the list, right? thank you bro